# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start while executing selenium python script on ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running following python3 script on ubuntu

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/admin/web/web.com/public_html/scripts/az/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

Running as normal user, I am getting following error:

```
$ python3 getStock.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getStock.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/admin/web/web.com/public_html/scripts/az/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551591 (bcc4a2cdef0f6b942b2bb8049068f65340fa2a69),platform=Linux 4.2.0-042stab120.16 x86_64)
```

Trying with sudo also; still I am getting following error

```
$ sudo python3 getStock.py
[sudo] password for admin:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getStock.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/admin/web/web.com/public_html/scripts/az/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551591 (bcc4a2cdef0f6b942b2bb8049068f65340fa2a69),platform=Linux 4.2.0-042stab120.16 x86_64)
```

Not sure what is going on? I have tried following;

1. I have tried updating selenium;
2. I have tried running as python 2.x and python 3.x
3. I have tried running the script as a normal user
   and sudo user
4. I have tried changing the permissions to even chmod 777

Here are my versions:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Python 3.5.2
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (3.11.0)
```

Comment: Does adding `options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')` solve it?

Comment: for me this was an intermittent issue. closing all other browser instances and rerunning the program fixed it. I don't think `r` as the accepted answer mentioned makes much of a difference in python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start
```

...implies that your *WebClient* **Chrome** failed to start.

### Solution

You need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* through single forward slash i.e. `\` along with the raw i.e. `r` switch as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/home/admin/web/web.com/public_html/scripts/az/chromedriver')
```

### Additional Steps

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 2):

The real error is `unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally` .

Since , you are using `chromedriver=2.38.551591`.

Just make sure whether you are using correct chromedriver version  with respect to the chrome browser installed on your local machine.

Your version of chromedriver works with *chrome browser versions > 67.xx*

You can refer this [page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for compatibility references.

Answer (score 0):

this code below is working for me on the same environment (but my chromedriver version is  2.36):

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--window-position=0,0")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path", chrome_options=options)
```

Check if it works for you :)